# How to send SQL table data with Web Activity of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

1. I have Lookup with query "Select CustomerName, CustomerSales From Customers"
2. I have Web Activity for Notification purpose and I would like to send list of CustomerNames and Customer Sales. (For example Tesla, 1234000. There are 1-50 rows)
3. I can successfully send static text with Web Activity, but don't know how to build body for sending all data.

How to send data from table with Web Activity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have unselected "firs row" only option inside Lookup activity. If yes, then your lookup data will actually come as array in output json of lookup activity.

So, you should consider writing below expression to get that array.
`@activity('Fetch').output.value`